# How to make a query includes both count and data of collection

Tags: mongodb, moralis

Example data

```
[
   { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '13 May 2022 at 04:20:21 UTC'},
   { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '13 May 2022 at 06:20:21 UTC'},
   { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '13 May 2022 at 03:20:21 UTC'},
   { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '12 May 2022 at 07:39:34 UTC'},
   { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '12 May 2022 at 07:39:34 UTC'},
   { owner: '0x454545627', createdAt: '11 May 2022 at 04:13:48 UTC'}
]
```

And I want to query return data like this

```
[
  { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '13 May 2022', count: 3},
  { owner: '0x123124124', createdAt: '13 May 2022', count: 2},
  { owner: '0x454545627', createdAt: '11 May 2022', count: 1},
]
```

I have rounded with this for hours.
Thanks for help.

Comment: i think you should save normal dates on the database, and from them you can get the string if you want in many formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set `createdAt` with

   1.1. `$trim` - Trim string from *1.1.1*.

   1.1.1. `$arrayElemAt` - Get the first value from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$split` - Split `createdAt` string with word "at".
2. `$group` - Group by `owner` and `createdAt` and perform count.
3. `$project` - Decorate output documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      createdAt: {
        $trim: {
          input: {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$createdAt",
                  "at"
                ]
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        owner: "$owner",
        createdAt: "$createdAt"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      owner: "$_id.owner",
      createdAt: "$_id.createdAt",
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Pys7ZQ5j3X)

Comment: Side note: Will be easier to use `$dateFromString` to replace for `$trim` - `$arrayElemAt` - `$split` flow. But the word month: "May" is not supported in [format specifier](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#std-label-dateFromString-format-specifiers) unless the month is "05" in string. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TWVredN2ttg)